# InlineModelAdmin not showing up on admin page

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin

# Create your models here.


class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class BookInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book

class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
            BookInline,
        ]
```

registered on my admin page, however books are not showing up in the author's admin page. Am I misunderstanding how this will work? I want to be able to add and remove books from the author on the admin page.

Comment: can you show the code you put in your admin.py?

Comment: could you click on the check mark (under the vote arrow) to accept this answer as well? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what you should have in admins.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import Author, Book

class BookInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Book


class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ BookInline ]

admin.site.register(Author, AuthorAdmin)
admin.site.register(Book)
```

You probably forgot to include 'AuthorAdmin' in this line:

```
admin.site.register(Author, AuthorAdmin)
```